# Обособляются ли слова "как обычно"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

> В душе всё бушует(,) как обычно.

Как мне кажется, здесь "как обычно" не находится в тесной смысловой связи со сказуемым, поэтому должно обособляться. Но вот только когда начинаю читать данное предложение вслух, никакой паузы не слышно, да и поставить её было бы неуместно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что запятая уместна.

Сравнительный оборот обособляется,

> 4) если оборот выражается сочетанием как правило, как исключение, как
>   обычно, как всегда, как прежде, как сейчас, как теперь, как нарочно и
>   т. п. (некоторые из них имеют характер вводных слов), например: Вижу,
>   как теперь, самого хозяина… (Пушкин); Занятия начались, как обычно, в
>   девять часов утра; Помню, как сейчас, свою первую учительницу в школе;
>   Как нарочно, в кармане не было ни копейки; Запятыми, как правило,
>   выделяются деепричастные
>   обороты.

https://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/332/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B

Answer (score 2):

**В душе всё бушУет, как обЫчно.**

***Как обычно***  — здесь вводное слово, оборот не обособляется только в том случае, если входит в сказуемое (тесно связано со сказуемым), например: *А дальше все опять было как обычно* (В. Пелевин).

**Пауза есть** как при обособлении, так  и без обособления вводного слова, просто во втором случае она обозначена как перелом интонации (имеет меньшую длительность).

В обоих случаях предложение состоит из двух фраз, а каждая фраза имеет тоническое ударение. При отсутствии обособления это выглядит так: *В душе всё бушУет //как обЫчно*.

Но ***как обычно***  — это (по смыслу) не обстоятельство образа действия.  Нельзя сказать, что бушует каким-то определенным образом. Бушует,  потому что так происходит часто (обычно).

**Поэтому вводное слово нужно обособить.**

Comment: Вводное слово входит в сказуемое? Можно так говорить? Или если входит, то оно уже не вводное?

Comment: Вы, как всегда, правы. Нельзя так говорить.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, постановка запятой меняет смысл. Если бушует (как?) как обычно, то тесная связь со сказуемым есть и запятая не ставится, я если обычно в душе все бушует, и в этот нет ничего нового, то запятую нужно ставить, да и паузу я бы сделал.

Дополнение. Вариант, в котором акцентируется внимание на способе "бушевания" (как обычно или другим образом), я привел с некоторой долей иронии, вряд ли такой подход был у автора в мыслях.

Comment: Получается, если мы добавим часть "а сердцу хочется перемен", то постановка запятой обязательна?

Comment: Если сердцу хочется, чтобы бушевало по-другому — без запятой,  а если хочется, чтобы перестало бушевать, то с запятой.